# SWRevealViewController with Google maps IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController with Google Maps.My rear view controller loads google map. Problem is that first time it loads google map with my current location correctly but when i redirect to different screen from menu and comes back to google map screen from menu again instead of going to my current location it goes to some where in UK.

My Code: For Google Map view controller

```
    override func viewDidLoad() 
     {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   locationManager.delegate = self
   locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

   searchResultController = SearchResultsController()
   searchResultController.delegate = self

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
       self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
   })

   if revealViewController() != nil {  
       menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
       menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
       self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
   }
 }

  func locateWithLongitude(lon: Double, andLatitude lat: Double, andTitle title: String) {

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

       let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
       let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)

       let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(lat, longitude: lon, zoom: :sunglasses:
       self.mapView.camera = camera

       marker.title = "Address : \(title)"
       marker.map  = self.mapView           
   }
}

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
 {
   if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse
   {
       locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
       mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
       mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
   }
 }


  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

   if let location = locations.last {
       mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 8, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
       locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()        
   }
  }

  func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

   let placeClient = GMSPlacesClient()
   placeClient.autocompleteQuery(searchText, bounds: nil, filter: nil) { (results,error: NSError?) -> Void in

       self.resultsArray.removeAll()
       if results == nil{
           return
       }

       for result in results! {
           //if let result  = result as? GMSAutocompletePrediction {
           self.resultsArray.append(result.attributedFullText.string)
       }     
       self.searchResultController.reloadDataWithArray(self.resultsArray)
   }
```

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hirrn.png)